# Just and dot in winghci

Tags: haskell, pointfree, option-type

Why does this work...

```
Just.(+3) $ 6.7
Just $ truncate 8.9
```

...but not this?

```
Just.truncate $ 8.9
```

I tried resolving truncate to a simple Double -> Int:

```
let f :: Double -> Int; f = (\ x -> truncate x);
```

...but that doesn't appear to be the problem...

```
Just.f $ 5.6

<interactive>:41:1:
Failed to load interface for `Just'
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you mean to compose functions, it's better to write `f . g` than `f.g`. It's a little more readable, and you avoid a bunch of problems like this one.

When you have something of the form `Foo.bar` or `Foo.Bar` in Haskell, it is parsed as a qualified name. That's why `Just.f` doesn't work: `Just` isn't a module, so the 'interface' for `Just` can't be loaded.

Why `Just.(+3)` does work as intended: `(+3)` is a right section, not an identifier, so the dot can't be part of a qualified name. The only way to interpret it is to assume that `.` is an infix application of the operator `(.)`, so it must be `Just . (+3)`.

Comment: Interesting about that right section, I was wondering why it would work myself!

Comment: Basically, this is a really hairy part of Haskell syntax, which has become a "necessary evil". The original language didn't have qualified names, and didn't foresee this problem.

Comment: @jpaugh: I'd argue it would _not_ have been necessary if somebody hadn't insisted the hierarchy seperator should be `.` (IMO a bad choice for Haskell anyway, since `.` is so common for something really quite different). If it was `/` (_at least_ as reasonable, since UNIX file systems have rather more to do with most Haskell projects than any language which uses `.` for method / struct-member qualifying), then we wouldn't have this trouble: a type with no-argument ADT constructors couldn't really have much of a useful `Fractional` instance!

Comment: Hmm. `/` would be reasonable, yet highly peculiar. (More chance for *developer* confusion, rather than in the compiler.) Well, they sure couldn't have chosen `::`, that's for sure.

Comment: While we're on it, we should swap `:` and `::` ;)

Answer (score 4):

A dot between a capitalized identifier and another identifier is parsed as a qualified name (eg. `Data.Map.insert`), so the error is telling you that it couldn't find a module named `Just`. You can simply add spaces around the dot to fix this.